# print the decimal equivalent of a binary number in java

Tags: java, binary, decimal

My code is to print the decimal equivalent of a binary number entered by user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a binary integer: ");
        int b=in.nextInt();
        int digits=1;
        int q=b;
        //determine the number of digits
        while(q/10>=1){     
            ++digits;
            q/=10;
        }
        System.out.println(digits);
        int decimal=0;
        int i=0;
        //pick off the binary number's digits and calculate the decimal equivalent
        while(i<=digits-1){
            decimal+=b/Math.pow(10,i)%10*Math.pow(2,i);
            i++;
        }           
        System.out.println(decimal);

    }

}
```

When I enter 1101, it outputs 13, which is the right answer. However, when I 
test the number 11001, the decimal equivalent is supposed to be 25, but it outputs 26. I try 
to fix it but can't find where the bug is. Can you guys help me out?

Comment: If you're trying to get the user to input a binary number, you shouldn't ask for an integer; a `String` would be more appropriate.  First of all, asking for an integer limits you to 10 bits since the largest possible decimal integer is 10 digits.  Second, you can't generalize it to hexadecimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `Math.pow` returns a floating-point number, and you're doing floating-point calculations where you think you're doing integer calculations.  When `i` is 4, and you calculate

```
b/Math.pow(10,i)%10*Math.pow(2,i);
```

the calculation goes like this:

```
b = 11001
b / Math.pow(10,i) = b / 10000 = 1.1001 (not 1)
1.1001 % 10 = 1.1001
1.1001 * Math.pow(2,i) = 1.1001 * 16 = 17.6016 (not 16)
```

This is then cast to an `(int)` when you add it to `decimal`.  It truncates the last value to 17, but it's too late.

Casting the `Math.pow` results to an `(int)` will make it work.  But this isn't the right approach anyway.  If you want to learn how to do it yourself instead of using `parseInt`, it's best to input the number as a `String` (see my earlier comment), and then you don't have to worry about picking off the bits as decimal digits or powers of 10 at all anyway.  Even using your approach, instead of `Math.pow` it would be simpler to keep `powerOf10` and `powerOf2` integer variables that you modify with `powerOf10 *= 10; powerOf2 *= 2;` in each loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I've learned a lot...BTW, how to do that using String input?

Comment: Use `charAt` to access each character.  The easiest way is to keep a running sum.  Look at the string from left to right.  For each character that's a `'0'`, double the current sum; if it's a `'1'`, double the current sum and add 1.  Anything else is an error.  The same principle can be used for any base: multiply the current value by the base and add the value of each digit, going from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a binary integer: ");
        int b=in.nextInt();
        int answer = Integer.parseInt(in.nextInt() + "", 2);
        System.out.println("The number is " + answer + ".");
    }
}
```

2 is for base 2.